# Importing from excel works with ImportExportModelAdmin but not through user created import view

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I have an excel file with data of employees... The unit name field in the excel sheet is linked to the unit table which is another model.

Have included the `ForeignKeyWidget` in `resources.py` to look for the unit while importing and it works with django's inbuilt `ImportExportModelAdmin`.

While importing through the user made view it throws following error.

```
['“A Unit” value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.']
```

`resources.py`

```
from import_export import resources, fields
from import_export.widgets import ForeignKeyWidget
from sqlalchemy import column

from . models import *

class EmployeeResource(resources.ModelResource):
    id = fields.Field(attribute='id', column_name='id')
    EmpID = fields.Field(attribute='EmpID', column_name='EmpID')
    Name = fields.Field(attribute='Name', column_name='Name')
    DOB = fields.Field(attribute='DOB', column_name='DOB')
    PresentUnit = fields.Field(attribute='PresentUnit', column_name='PresentUnit', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Unit, 'UnitName'))
    PostInDate = fields.Field(attribute='PostInDate', column_name='PostInDate')
 
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
```

`views.py`

```
@login_required(login_url='accounts:login')
def upload_employee_view(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        file = request.FILES['employeefile']
        dataset = Dataset()

        if not file.name.endswith('xlsx'):
            messages.info(request, "Incorrect File Format, Upload aborted")
            return render(request, 'employee/uploademployee.html')

        employee_data = dataset.load(file.read(), format='xlsx')
        for employee in employee_data:
            value = Employee(
                employee[0],
                employee[1],
                employee[2],
                employee[3],
                employee[4],
                employee[5],         
            )
            value.save()

    return render(request, 'employee/uploademployee.html')
```

In addition is there a way such that if an employee already exists with a given EmpID the record of that particular employee will get updated rather than a new record being created.

And also any way to avoid the compulsion of an id column to be included in the excel sheet which has to be uploaded

Comment: If you can use the django-import-export site, this will handle the process for you.  Your custom method bypasses django-import-export completely (it only uses DataSet).  I suggest go through the django-import-export docs carefully and this will help you understand.  The answer to your other two questions is "yes" (also described in the docs).  If you are still having problems, post back with clear details and we can try and help.

Comment: How can i access the django-import-export site through the user created template? Currently the documents only point towards accessing the import-export feature in the django admin and not through the user created template...                                                  Hence, I tried to create an import feature for accessing through the user template but it throws an error as described in the sixth line

Comment: If you have your own template (i.e. instead of using the Admin site), then you will have to study the Admin site code and reproduce that in your custom template.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this way is smart, but it simplest workaround:

1. Check format of date string inside Excel file:
   `print(employee[5])` for example
2. Let say it will be `2021/11/02 16:36:23`
3. Convert it to `datetime`
4. Convert it to `string` you need

```
from datetime import datetime

string_datetime = '2021/11/02 16:36:23'
input_format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
output_format = '%Y-%m-%d'
formatted_string_date = datetime.strptime(string_datetime, input_format).strftime(output_format)

print(formatted_string_date)
```

```
2021-11-02
```